# How are Sisal ropes compared to Manila ropes in Gym Climbing, in terms of hand feel as well as other characteristics?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, bodyweight, calisthenics, crossfit, gymnastics

How are Sisal ropes compared to Manila ropes in Gym Climbing, in terms of hand feel as well as other characteristics?

I wish to learn and slowly build capacity for Gym Rope Climbing.

Let's assume we are talking about standard 1.5" width of Climbing Rope.